# I have a super simple stored procedure that is giving me issues

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a super simple stored procedure that is giving me issues

The code is below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Kris Nelson
-- Create date: 08/17/2020
-- Description: Taking datetime and turning it into a string. 
-- =============================================
alter PROCEDURE sp_timeconversion 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @endtime datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temptime time
    DECLARE @militaryendtime varchar(20)

    SELECT @temptime = CAST(@endtime AS TIME)
    SELECT @militaryendtime = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, @temptime),0,6)
    
    RETURN @militaryendtime

END
GO
```

When running

```
EXEC sp_timeconversion @endtime = '2020-08-17 16:43:56.583'
```

I get this error

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_timeconversion, Line 17
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '16:43' to data type int.
```

Though I never convert to an int and I'm unsure where it's getting that?

Any advice?

Sorry I know it's a very simple question but I can't seem to understand what's throwing it for a loop.

Comment: Is this MySQL???  Doesn't look like MySQL to me.  Please tag your question properly!

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand?  How are you suppose to convert '16.43' into an int?

Answer (score 1):

The return argument to a stored proc is supposed to return a status or some other integer value. You cant return a string.

You need to use either define a return argument or use a simple

```
select @militaryendtime
```

which will return it as a 1 line, 1 column result set.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider making this code a function rather than a stored procedure which expects to have a returned value by default.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15